# How to call custom JS and CSS files from CSHTML in .Net core

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-3.1

I have a .net core project where the css, js and images are in different folders.

[image: JS path]

[image: CSS path]

The index.cshtml is in "\TechBlog.Web\Views\Home"

[image: Index cshtml path]

I'm trying to call the CSS and JS files from Index.cshtml. However, its not loading.

```
  @{
     ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
  }
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
  <head>
  //Load CSS
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/all.css">
  </head>
  <body>
  //Load JS
  <script src="../js/Jquery3.4.1.min.js"></script>
  </body>
```

Please note that, there  other line of codes. However, I just looking at, what I'm doing wrong for providing path.

I have added my JS and CSS files into WWWroot and using Visual Studio code. However, I don't see the files added in the folder getting reflected in the Visual Studio code explorer.

Am I providing the path incorrectly? Or there is something wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Try `css/all.css` and `js/Jquery3.4.1.min.js` (without the leading `..`)

Comment: why not use a relative path? `/js` or virtual path `~/js`

Answer (score 1):

you should use this:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../css/all.css">
```

Or

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/~/css/all.css">
```

Comment: This is very generalize and This will not work.Its .net core.

Answer (score 0):

you most change default static folder from wwwroot to root in startup.cs > Configure :

```
 app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
    {
        FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(env.ContentRootPath),
        RequestPath = "/"
    });
```

then :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/all.css">
```